# A list saved in txt file with strings starting with p showing weirdly in notepad

Tags: windows, unicode, rendering, notepad

This is what notepad shows: 
[image]

And this is what i actually saved:- 
[image]
(This picture was taken using `wsl cat voice_list.txt`)

Can anyone explain what happened wrong in the notepad that it displays weird unicode char's?

PS: I saw the UTF-16 below so i tried to saving it as UTF-8 and ASNI but it converted itself back to UTF-16

EDIT: As @JosefZ requested

```
['p225', 'p226', 'p227', 'p228', 'p229', 'p230', 'p231', 'p232', 'p233', 'p234', 'p236', 'p237', 'p238', 'p239', 'p240', 'p241', 'p243', 'p244', 'p245', 'p246', 'p247', 'p248', 'p249', 'p250', 'p251', 'p252', 'p253', 'p254', 'p255', 'p256', 'p257', 'p258', 'p259', 'p260', 'p261', 'p262', 'p263', 'p264', 'p265', 'p266', 'p267', 'p268', 'p269', 'p270', 'p271', 'p272', 'p273', 'p274', 'p275', 'p276', 'p277', 'p278', 'p279', 'p280', 'p281', 'p282', 'p283', 'p284', 'p285', 'p286', 'p287', 'p288', 'p292', 'p293', 'p294', 'p295', 'p297', 'p298', 'p299', 'p300', 'p301', 'p302', 'p303', 'p304', 'p305', 'p306', 'p307', 'p308', 'p310', 'p311', 'p312', 'p313', 'p314', 'p316', 'p317', 'p318', 'p323', 'p326', 'p329', 'p330', 'p333', 'p334', 'p335', 'p336', 'p339', 'p340', 'p341', 'p343', 'p345', 'p347', 'p351', 'p360', 'p361', 'p362', 'p363', 'p364', 'p374', 'p376']
```

Hex dump:-

```
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
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content (something like `wsl hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' voice_list.txt`, please).

Comment: Also while unminify-ing on websites (originally this was in json format with some values) i errors as invalid json or invalid string

Answer (score 1):

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
my_string = "['p225', 'p226', 'p227', 'p228']"
print( my_string.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'utf-16-le'))
```

> ```
> ❛㉰㔲Ⱗ✠㉰㘲Ⱗ✠㉰㜲Ⱗ✠㉰㠲崧
> ```

Not much more to say about this kind of mojibake origin and mechanism without knowing *hexadecimal dump* of the file (or, at least, some few starting bytes of the file)…